# Graphing a linear equation in html5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm using this tutorial: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-graphing-an-equation/

Inside the `drawEquation` method, there is another method `transformContext` (line 153) that is called:

```
transformContext = function() {
        var context = this.context;

        // move context to center of canvas
        this.context.translate(this.centerX, this.centerY);

        /*
         * stretch grid to fit the canvas window, and
         * invert the y scale so that that increments
         * as you move upwards
         */
        context.scale(this.scaleX, -this.scaleY);
      };
```

This method makes it possible to graph equations referencing a `0,0 origin` as opposed to the top-left origin of the canvas (I know this because i commented it out and observed the results). However, I dont understand what is happening inside this method. How does a `translate` to the center of the canvas and a `scale` make it possible to draw equations from the origin?

The comments in the code are not that helpful either. How does moving the context or stretching it cause this effect?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really drawing from the origin, per se.  In fact, the equation drawer doesn't even know there are axes present.  The function just draws based on what it knows about the canvas.  It knows a canvas width, and it knows how many "units" you told it to divide that canvas width into (20x20 in this case since the "scale" is from -10 to 10 on each axis; those parameters are provided in `minX`, `minY`, etc).

It can draw things on a pixel by pixel basis at the center (the context), starting from -minX (an offset to the left side) and progressing to maxX (offset to the right), and then "scale" it based on the number of pixels per scale unit.  In this case, that happens in a slightly different order (the scale is applied before drawing, at line 136), but that's the gist.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `translate()` on a context, this adds to the x and y coordinates where things will later be drawn. So, for example, suppose I do this:

```
context.translate(100, 200);
context.fillRect(0, 0, 30, 40);
```

The rectangle will actually be drawn at (100, 200, 30, 40), because I translated before drawing it.

The scale() method has a similar effect, but instead of adding to the x and y, it multiplies them. If one of the scale factors is negative, this then has the effect of flipping whatever you draw along that axis.

So, suppose I do this:

```
context.translate(100, 200);
context.scale(30, -30);
```

Now I draw a line:

```
context.moveTo(0, 0);
context.lineTo(5, 8);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
context.moveTo(0 * 30 + 100, 0 * -30 + 200);
context.lineTo(5 * 30 + 100, 8 * -30 + 200);
```

So, the translate and scale has the effect that the origin is now at (100, 200), moving 1 in the x direction goes right 30, and moving 1 in the y direction goes up 30.